# Image doesn't repeat

Tags: html, css, animation

I was wondering why my background image is not repeating when I have background repeat set to repeat. I am using bootstrap, that is why there is a col-lg-6 there. I am a new to coding and I wanted to test my skills by making an exact copy of another website. [This is the website](http://I%20am%20a%20new%20to%20coding%20and%20I%20wanted%20to%20test%20my%20skills%20by%20making%20an%20exact%20copy%20of%20another%20website.%20This%20is%20the%20website:%20thefront.maccarianagency.com%20If%20you%20go%20to%20that,%20you%20can%20see%20exactly%20want%20I%20want.). If you go to that, you can see exactly want I want.

```css
.image-div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#float {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background:url(https://assets.maccarianagency.com/the-front/web-screens/home/home-hero-bg-dark.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  -webkit-animation: moving-img 7s infinite linear;
  animation: moving-img 7s infinite linear;
}




@keyframes moving-img {
  0% {
      transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-15deg) scale(1);
  }

  100% {
      transform: translate(-400px, -600px) rotate(-15deg) scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 image-div" style="height: 80vh; width: 50vw;">
  <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Where is `#float` in the html structure?

Comment: I think there may be two uses of the 'repeat' concept here. There is the repeat of the animation, which is happening OK. But, do you want the whole div to be completely covered by the background image(s) all the time? At the moment you only get one instance of it because it exactly fits the div (and the transform is irrelevant to its thinking here). It can be done but needs more styling, let us know if that's what you want.

Comment: What I want is for the background image to repeat in the animation and cover the whole section. I am a new to coding and I wanted to test my skills by making an exact copy of another website. This is the website: https://thefront.maccarianagency.com/ If you go to that, you can see exactly want I want. I've been trying to figure out how to repeat it for a few days but I cant figure it out. Your help would be much appreciated as it will help me learn more.

Comment: #float is supposed to be the #image that is shown there. I dont know why but I mixed them up when I was putting the code snippits in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of thinking of this is that there is a continuous scroll upwards on the image div, and then we rotate that div 15%.

First therefore we need to get a continuous scroll. This can be achieved by putting both a before and after pseudo element on the image div which have the required background. These then both get animated upwards, one starting at `top: 0` one starting at `top: 100%`. That way the scroll is continuous - the after pseudo element follows up immediately after the before one.

So far so good, but when we rotate the image div, there are gaps where the parent div shows through. So we make the before and after pseudo elements twice the size in both directions, get their background images repeated and adjust their positions so they always cover the parent div. The parent is also given `overflow: hidden` so we don't see the extra bits.

Here is a working snippet. Note that the choice of having the background images 30% of width is arbitrary - change it to what you want.

Note also that the website that is to be copied has a bug, though minor. Every so often you see a slight jerk in the scrolling. We have overcome that problem here by having the two sets of background animate independently so as the second one gets to the top, the first takes on opacity 0 for a split second as it repositions itself back to the top. This fools us into thinking it's all continuous. That website has also put a 'sloping' white over part of the div but that was not part of the question asked here.

```css
.container {
}

.image-div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-15deg) translateX(-25%) translateY(-25%);
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image::before, #image::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 30% auto;
  background-image:url(https://assets.maccarianagency.com/the-front/web-screens/home/home-hero-bg-dark.png);
  background-repeat: repeat repeat;
  
  -webkit-animation: moving-img 7s infinite linear;
  animation: moving-img 7s infinite linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

#image::after {
  top:100%;
}

@keyframes moving-img {
  0% {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  opacity: 1;
  }

  99.95% {
      transform: translateY(-100%);
      opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
      opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 image-div" style="height: 80vh; width: 50vw;">
  <div id="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx so much!! This helped me a lot and I understand how this works now! Once again, thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Let me know if you succeed.

```
<style>
.image-div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#float {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background:url(https://assets.maccarianagency.com/the-front/web-screens/home/home-hero-bg-dark.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  -webkit-animation: moving-img 7s infinite linear;
  animation: moving-img 7s infinite linear;
}




@keyframes moving-img {
  0% {
      transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(-15deg) scale(1);
  }

  100% {
      transform: translate(-400px, -600px) rotate(-15deg) scale(1);
  }
}
</style>
<div class="col-lg-6 image-div" style="height: 80vh; width: 50vw;">
  <div id="float"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I still get the same result that I do with my code. What I want is it to do exactly as this website: https://thefront.maccarianagency.com/. I am trying to recreate this template to test my skills and this is the last thing left.